# Inline Python "for" to read lines from file and append to list

Tags: arrays, for-loop, inline, readline

I have this code:

```
self.y_file = with open("y_file.txt", "r") as g: y_data.append(line for line in g.readlines())
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I am more than sure the problem lies within 1) How I open the file (with) and that for loop. Any way I could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just open and read. If you want auto-close you need to wrap it in function

```
self.y_file = open('y_file.txt').readlines()
```

Or:

```
   def read_file(fname):
      with open(fname) as f:
        return f.readlines()


   self.y_file = read_file('y_file.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I've also added self.y_data.append(**your code**) to make it do what I want! Sometimes I feel the answer is right in front of my face.

Comment: @Benjamin, note that python list has extend(), so for example, in your question, instead of  y_data.append(line for line in g.readlines()) - you can write y_data.extend(g.readlines())